# how to resolve this query below and what is the purpose of using IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

```
update radcheck SET radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' where radcheck.username IN (select username from radpostauth where radpostauth.username = $mobile AND radpostauth.authdate < now() - 120)");
```

i want my query to update column "attribute" of a username in radcheck table when the same username in radpostauth table has value "reject" in his  reply column
i need to first update radpostauth.reply = 'reject' on the basis of radpostauth.authdate

Comment: What is the purpose of using IN operator ? , depends! ,, but why you are using it if you don't even know , what it does. Check this link to know about IN Clause : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: The purpose is to solve the problem of not knowing how to write a query properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use join in mysql query because better performance use join instead of  inner query

```
update radcheck as rc
JOIN radpostauth asrpa ON (rpa.username = rc.username)  AND (rpa.authdate < now() - 120)
SET rc.attribute = 'rejected' 
where rpa.reply = 'reject';
```

Comment: thank you for query bhavik hey if i have around or more than 10000 records then which should i use for better speed and performance subquery or joins

Comment: i need to first update radpostauth.reply = 'reject' on the basis of radpostauth.authdate <NOW() - 60 and then i have to update radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' by matching the radcheck.username with = radpostauth.username on the basis of radpostauth.reply = 'reject'

Comment: any reply please i am stuck

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you please use JOIN with update query

```
    update radcheck 
JOIN radpostauth ON radpostauth.authdate < now() - 120
SET radpostauth.reply = 'reject'


update radcheck 
JOIN radpostauth ON (radpostauth.username = radcheck.username)  AND (radpostauth.authdate < now() - 120)
SET radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' 
where radpostauth.reply = 'reject';
```

Comment: i need to first update radpostauth.reply = 'reject' on the basis of radpostauth.authdate <NOW() - 60 and then i have to update radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' by matching the radcheck.username with = radpostauth.username on the basis of radpostauth.reply = 'reject'

Comment: then you need to set up two update query if you want then i will update my code give exmple

Comment: but how can i run these two updates queries together and can i use this query as an scheduled mysql  event

Comment: first execute first update query then second one update query

Comment: actually i have to create a mysql event so i need all this in one single query that would resolve everything. can we use union or any other thing like multiquery

Answer (score 0):

based on your description you shuold subseelect the username where adpostauth table has value "reject" in his reply column

```
update radcheck 
SET radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' 
where radcheck.username IN (select username 
                        from radpostauth
                        where radpostauth.reply  = 'reject' ");
```

Comment: i need to first update radpostauth.reply = 'reject' on the basis of radpostauth.authdate <NOW() - 60 and then i have to update radcheck.attribute = 'rejected' by matching the radcheck.username with = radpostauth.username on the basis of radpostauth.reply = 'reject'